# How to block copy paste from clipboard in Android 2.3?

Tags: android

I have asked here just 3 days ago about blocking copy paste operations in Android through clipboard. I got the solution for that but the clipboardmanager class is not working for 2.3 devices.

Answer (score 2):

`android.text.ClipboardManager` is for API level <11

`android.content.ClipboardManager` is for API level >=11

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

So what you want is a listener on the clipboard. That is not possible in API level < 11. What you can do is a hack. You can create an Asyntask/Service that is always running endlessly that keeps clearing the clipboard.

Something like:

```
  private class  mClipBoardTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    final android.text.ClipboardManager manager;
    private mClipBoardTask()
    {
        manager = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        do
        {
            if(!manager.getText().equals(""))
                manager.setText("");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while (true);
    }
}
```

And call this async like:

```
new mClipBoardTask().execute();
```

Comment: Yes buddy I have gone through this already but how to achieve my objective for 2.3 devices. :)

Comment: Update your code for other API level so we can help you.

Comment: Let me try with this solution...but I think it will consume more battery power. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: That's the only solution because there is nothing on the API for that. It will not consume more battery power. I've edited the answer anyway. I should run smoother now.

Comment: Hi @Pedro, I have tested the code suggested by you for 2.3 devices but its hanging the UI thread for the application. May be this is because of the infinite while loop..

Comment: Try this new code please. Let me know if you notice any change.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code to resolve my problem, but this works from api level 11

```
primaryListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {  

            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newPlainText("MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN", "");  
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newHtmlText("MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML", "", "");
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_INTENT)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newIntent("MIMETYPE_TEXT_INTENT", null);
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_URILIST)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "MIMETYPE_TEXT_URILIST", uri);
                }

                clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipObject);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "copy/paste is blocked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this section in oncreate:

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardListener() );
```

sub class in Activity:

```
class ClipboardListener implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener
    {
       public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
       {
          // do something useful here with the clipboard
          // use getText() method

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "copy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           clipBoard.setText("you are Tracked by me ");
           clipBoard.setPrimaryClip(null);
       }

    }
}
```